# Access directory anywhere using CD in Command Prompt (Windows)

Tags: windows, cmd, chdir

I want to access a directory using the CHDIR (CD) command in CMD without typing the entire path.
For example:

```
C:\Program Files> cd Coding
```

And then, the result I want is:

```
C:\Users\Shadow\Documents\Coding>
```

Is it possible to be done? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Use wildcards. `cd C:\U*\S*\D*\Coding`

Comment: @NekoMusume, wildcards can only be used in the *last* element of a path…

Comment: @aschipfl I tested it this way and it worked for me... Try `cd \U*\A*\De*`

Comment: Oh, sorry, @NekoMusume! I forgot about this specific behaviour of `cd`. But note that this changes to the first directory it finds that begins with `U` and so on, so you might end up in then wrong one…

Comment: I am aware that it will try that but it also has to satisfy the rest of the wildcards so that may be unlikely unless you have folders like `\Ums\Asdfghjkl\Destruction` or something like that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `system variable` which `variable` is `Coding` and `value` is `C:\Users\Shadow\Documents\Coding`.
Now you can use `cd %Coding%` to go to your desire path.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't natively support CDPATH like some other OS's, but there are other solutions.

One option would be to set a Variable to the path that you want to CD to.

If you run

`set Coding=C:\Users\Shadow\Documents\Coding`

you can subsequently run

`cd %Coding%`

and be directed to the correct directory.

If you want to make this permanent, you would use setx instead.

`setx Coding C:\Users\Shadow\Documents\Coding`

Another option would be to modify how your CD works, as per this: https://superuser.com/questions/224024/cdpath-in-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

You could define a macro using the [`doskey` command](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html):

```cmd
doskey Coding=cd /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Coding"
```

To use the macro just type this:

```cmd
Coding
```